"Yaw Drift Issue in STM32F103 Integration with MPU6050 and HMC5883L"
I integrated an STM32F103RT6TR with an MPU6050 and HMC5883L to calculate acceleration, gyroscope, pitch, roll, and yaw values. While everything else is working fine, the yaw value is drifting. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

void MPU6050_Calibrate(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
    uint8_t rawData[14];
    int16_t accel_raw[3], gyro_raw[3];
    int samples = 2000;

    printf("Calibrating...\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++)
    {
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(hi2c, MPU6050_ADDR, ACCEL_XOUT_H, 1, rawData, 14, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

        accel_raw[0] = (int16_t)(rawData[0] << 8 | rawData[1]);
        accel_raw[1] = (int16_t)(rawData[2] << 8 | rawData[3]);
        accel_raw[2] = (int16_t)(rawData[4] << 8 | rawData[5]);
        gyro_raw[0] = (int16_t)(rawData[8] << 8 | rawData[9]);
        gyro_raw[1] = (int16_t)(rawData[10] << 8 | rawData[11]);
        gyro_raw[2] = (int16_t)(rawData[12] << 8 | rawData[13]);

        accel_offset[0] += accel_raw[0];
        accel_offset[1] += accel_raw[1];
        accel_offset[2] += accel_raw[2];
        gyro_offset[0] += gyro_raw[0];
        gyro_offset[1] += gyro_raw[1];
        gyro_offset[2] += gyro_raw[2];

        //printf("Calibration %d\n",i);
    }

    // Average offsets
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        accel_offset[i] /= samples;
        gyro_offset[i] /= samples;
    }
    accel_offset[2] -= ACCEL_SCALE;  // Gravity adjustment
    printf("Calibration Done...\n");
}
// Read all data from MPU6050
void MPU6050_Read_All(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, float *accel, float *gyro, float *angles)
{
    uint8_t rawData[14];
    int16_t accel_raw[3], gyro_raw[3];
    float accel_angle[2];  // Roll and Pitch from accelerometer

    uint32_t current_time = HAL_GetTick();
    float dt = (current_time - last_time)/1000.0;  // time difference in seconds

    if(dt == 0)
        dt = 0.01; // fallback for very fast loops

    // Read accelerometer and gyroscope data
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(hi2c, MPU6050_ADDR, ACCEL_XOUT_H, 1, rawData, 14, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    // Convert raw data
    accel_raw[0] = (int16_t)(rawData[0] << 8 | rawData[1]);
    accel_raw[1] = (int16_t)(rawData[2] << 8 | rawData[3]);
    accel_raw[2] = (int16_t)(rawData[4] << 8 | rawData[5]);
    gyro_raw[0] = (int16_t)(rawData[8] << 8 | rawData[9]);
    gyro_raw[1] = (int16_t)(rawData[10] << 8 | rawData[11]);
    gyro_raw[2] = (int16_t)(rawData[12] << 8 | rawData[13]);

    // Scale the values
    accel[0] = (accel_raw[0] - accel_offset[0]) / ACCEL_SCALE;
    accel[1] = (accel_raw[1] - accel_offset[1]) / ACCEL_SCALE;
    accel[2] = (accel_raw[2] - accel_offset[2]) / ACCEL_SCALE;

    gyro[0] = (gyro_raw[0] - gyro_offset[0]) / GYRO_SCALE;
    gyro[1] = (gyro_raw[1] - gyro_offset[1]) / GYRO_SCALE;
    gyro[2] = (gyro_raw[2] - gyro_offset[2]) / GYRO_SCALE;

    // Calculate angles from accelerometer
    accel_angle[0] = atan2f(accel[1], sqrtf(accel[0] * accel[0] + accel[2] * accel[2])) * 180.0 / M_PI;  // Roll
    accel_angle[1] = atan2f(-accel[0], sqrtf(accel[1] * accel[1] + accel[2] * accel[2])) * 180.0 / M_PI;  // Pitch

    // Apply Kalman filter for roll and pitch
    angles[0] = Kalman_Filter(accel_angle[0], gyro[0], dt, &roll_state, &roll_bias);
    angles[1] = Kalman_Filter(accel_angle[1], gyro[1], dt, &pitch_state, &pitch_bias);

    float magnetometer_yaw = atan2f(mag_y, mag_x) * 180.0 / M_PI;  // Magnetometer-based yaw
    yaw = 0.98 * (yaw + gyro[2] * dt) + 0.02 * magnetometer_yaw;  // Complementary filter
    angles[2] = yaw;

    last_time = current_time;


}

void HMC5883L_Read_Mag(void)
{
    uint8_t mag_data[6];
    int16_t raw_x, raw_y, raw_z;

    // Read magnetometer data
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, HMC5883L_ADDR, HMC5883L_DATA_X_MSB, 1, mag_data, 6, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    // Combine high and low bytes
    raw_x = (int16_t)(mag_data[0] << 8 | mag_data[1]);
    raw_z = (int16_t)(mag_data[2] << 8 | mag_data[3]);
    raw_y = (int16_t)(mag_data[4] << 8 | mag_data[5]);

    // Convert to Gauss (apply scale if necessary)
    mag_x = (float)raw_x * MAG_SCALE;
    mag_y = (float)raw_y * MAG_SCALE;
}
// Kalman filter implementation
float Kalman_Filter(float accel_angle, float gyro_rate, float dt, float *state, float *bias)

{
    static float P[2][2] = { {1, 0}, {0, 1} };  // Initial error covariance
    const float Q_angle = 0.001, Q_bias = 0.003, R_measure = 0.03;  // Tuning parameters

    float rate = gyro_rate - *bias;
    *state += dt * rate;

    // Predict error covariance
    P[0][0] += dt * (dt * P[1][1] - P[0][1] - P[1][0] + Q_angle);
    P[0][1] -= dt * P[1][1];
    P[1][0] -= dt * P[1][1];
    P[1][1] += Q_bias * dt;

    // Kalman gain
    float S = P[0][0] + R_measure;
    float K[2] = { P[0][0] / S, P[1][0] / S };

    // Update state with measurement
    float y = accel_angle - *state;  // Measurement residual
    *state += K[0] * y;
    *bias += K[1] * y;

    // Update error covariance
    float P00_temp = P[0][0];
    float P01_temp = P[0][1];
    P[0][0] -= K[0] * P00_temp;
    P[0][1] -= K[0] * P01_temp;
    P[1][0] -= K[1] * P00_temp;
    P[1][1] -= K[1] * P01_temp;

    return *state;
}
 

In the main function, I initialize the MPU6050 and HMC5883L, then calibrate the MPU6050. Inside the while loop, I call HMC5883L_Read_Mag() followed by MPU6050_Read_All(&hi2c1, accel, gyro, angles).

What's the incoming format from the accelerometer? Signed 16 bit 2's complement big endian?

SO is not to recommend libraries but math related to the 6 (or 9)axis is much more complicated than your simple equations.  Integration of data from many MEMS sensors is not an easy task. Even noise removal from the raw data is quite a complicated DSP-related task.
In am using with success https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-mems1.html.
https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/X-CUBE-MEMS1/tree/main
